# Angular request returns NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: angular, api, ssl-certificate

is there a way for Angular to ignore the ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when I make an http request to an untrusted site?

Of course if I go to the URL address with the browser i can accept this error and it works, but I was looking for a better solution if there is one.

I can download the certificate from this url could that  be useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular .Net, To generate a developer certificate run
from your VScode terminal, go into api cd .\API\ and run the following code, to trust certificate.

```
dotnet dev-certs https or 
dotnet dev-certs https --trust (for windows and macOS only)
```

this will fix ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID